# Change format when exporting to CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro to export Excel to CSV:

```
Sub To_CSV()
Dim tmpWS As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If WS.Range("B1").Value <> "" Then
     If WS.Range("c1").Value <> "" Then
         filePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "Pozo de Bombeo " & WS.Range("B1").Value & ".csv"
     Else
         filePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "Pozo de Observacion " & WS.Range("B1").Value & ".csv"
     End If
     WS.Copy
     Set tmpWS = ActiveSheet
     tmpWS.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV
     tmpWS.Parent.Close False

End If
Next


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But when I open the the CSV "POZO DE BOMBEO" the format of some dates changed, apparently at random.

Comment: HI Diego, dates are a real issue in CSV format.  Could you provide what the format was before export, what you expect it to be, and how it appeared as examples?  This will help us understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of my output:

11/27/2018 11:19
11/27/2018 11:20
11/27/2018 11:25
11/27/2018 11:30
11/27/2018 11:35
11/27/2018 11:40
11/27/2018 11:45
11/27/2018 13:00
11/27/2018 16:00
11/27/2018 17:15
27-11-2018 22:10
27-11-2018 23:40
28-11-2018 1:10
28-11-2018 2:30
28-11-2018 3:40
28-11-2018 4:10
28-11-2018 5:10

The original input was DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM but as you can see, for some reason, it changed.  Luckily, I was able to reach the solution:

```
tmpWS.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
```

Just added: "local:= True" in the Workbook.SaveAs method.